# How is it possible for a MOSFET driver to increase both current and voltage? Where does the extra power come from?

Tags: voltage, power, current, mosfet-driver

I am learning about MOSFET drivers and I came across this [article here](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/fall14/group08/Documents/How%20to%20Implement%20a%20MOSFET%20with%20a%20Gate%20Driver-1.pdf).

In the article it says "A MOSFET driver IC translates TTL or CMOS logical signals, to a higher voltage and higher current".

I don't understand how it is possible to drive both a higher voltage and higher current at the same time. If Power = Voltage * Current, how is it possible to increase voltage without decreasing current and vice versa? Shouldn't you only be able to increase one while decreasing the other?

If someone could explain how we can acheive a higher voltage and current in a simple driver IC I would appreciate it.

Comment: A 50 W audio power amplifier delivers a current and voltage to the speaker that are **way** larger than the input signal from a tuner or phono cartridge.  Same thing here.  The input signal modulates the power from a source that is independent of the input.

Comment: The output power of the MOSFET driver is higher than the input power. From a "conservation of energy" standpoint the extra power is supplied by the DC power supply connection to the MOSFET driver. It is a bit like a power amplifier (but of course not exactly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand how it is possible to drive both a higher voltage and higher current at the same time. If Power = Voltage * Current, how is it possible to increase voltage without decreasing current and vice versa?

Like any amplifier, the gate driver takes some power from another source (the power supply pin) and uses it to deliver more power to its output than is provided to its input.